# Toggle disabled property using jQuery's prop() doesn't work

Tags: jquery

First, [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqnZz/3/).

```
$('#enableButtonB').click(function (e) {
   if($(e.target).is(':checked'))
   {
       $('#myButtonB').removeProp('disabled');
       alert('Enable Button B');
   }
   else
   {
       $('#myButtonB').prop('disabled', true); 
       alert('Disable Button B');
   }
});
```

I'm trying to use jQuery's `.prop()` and `removeProp()` methods to enable and disable a button based on some criteria. It seems to work fine until `removeProp()` is called on the element. After that any subsequent calls to `prop()` fail to disable to button.

What's the proper way to enable and disable an element repeatedly?

Comment: `$('element').prop('disabled', true/false)` where you use true if you want it to be disabled, or false if you want it enabled.

Comment: Your fiddle works fine for me on FF12.

Comment: Why don't you use .attr() and .removeAttr() instead of .prop() and .removeProp()

Comment: The jQuery docs are great http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/ says : "Note: Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead."

Comment: @iambriansreed Very good to know. Thanks for the heads up. I'll definitely be more careful with `removeProp()` in the future.

Comment: @ranganadh Because I was under the impression that after 1.6, `prop()` was now the preferred method for setting these properties. http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: I'm using `.prop()` only for changing `type` attribute, but never used  `.prop()` for disabling.

Comment: @JasonTowne Check out my fiddle in my answer. Reducing to `prop` to boolean makes it a lot easier to set.

Comment: @iambriansreed Yep, that's what I would probably do in actual code as well. I wanted to keep the same fiddle as simple as possible to make it easier to read/understand. Great example though. I already +1 your answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead of

```
.removeProp('disabled')
```

use

```
.prop('disabled',false)
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kqnZz/6/

Comment: @iambriansreed  It's an improper example anyway.

Comment: Those were intentionally left in, @iambriansreed. But if you insist: http://jsfiddle.net/kqnZz/8/

Comment: I'm randomly coming across this question/answer looking for something else (and I see that it is somewhat old), but an explanation as to *why* this change is required would be helpful. From jQuery's documentation (https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/), "Note: Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, **disabled**, or selected. **This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead.**"

Answer (score 17):

First, http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/KxGVa/

The jQuery docs are great. [`removeProp`](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp) says:

> **Note:** Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use `.prop()` to set these properties to `false` instead.

Change:

```
.removeProp('disabled')
```

...to...

```
.prop('disabled', false)
```

...and...

```
.prop('disabled', 'disabled')
```

...to...

```
.prop('disabled', true)
```

Answer (score 6):

Try if this short function solves your needs:

```
$("#enableButtonB").click(function(){
  $("#myButtonB").prop('disabled', function (_, val) { return ! val; });
});
```

Creds to user [Explosion Pills](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903293/toggle-disabled-attribute-in-jquery) for that sweet function :)

Answer (score 2):

This line will act as toggle disabled function:

```
$('#myButtonB').prop('disabled', !$('#myButtonB').prop('disabled'));
```

If you use it inside a jquery function you can use it like:

```
$('#enableButtonB').on('click', function() {
     $('#myButtonB').prop('disabled', !$('#myButtonB').prop('disabled'));
});
```