# toggle disabled attribute in jquery

Tags: jquery

I've a checkbox that enable or disable a select element

Actually I use this simple piece of code that works fine.

```
$("#filtri").change(function(){
    if ($("#menuContinenti").attr("disabled")) {
        $("#menuContinenti").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $("#menuContinenti").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

Is this the best way or is there something like a `.toggle()` function to switch between disabled/enabled?

Comment: If it is not broken...don't fix it :)

Comment: @FrançoisWahl yes it does work (as i wrote), but is this the best way to attemp this task? I hope jquery offers something like a .toggle() function to switch between boolean attributes like disabled

Comment: jQuery has a toggle but only to toggle visibility: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ I don't know of a jQuery build-in toggle for disable/enable but you can have a look at all of the effects in their docs: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery toggle input disabled attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702000/jquery-toggle-input-disabled-attribute)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggle input disabled attribute using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702000/toggle-input-disabled-attribute-using-jquery)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You should use `.prop` for disabled:

```
$("#menuContinenti").prop('disabled', function () {
   return ! $(this).prop('disabled');
});
```

UPDATE: didn't realize the current property value is an argument to the function; this version is even cleaner:

```
$("#menuContinenti").prop('disabled', function (_, val) { return ! val; });
```

UPDATE: ES2015

```
$("#menuContinenti").prop("disabled", (_, val) => !val);
```

Comment: It is nice and short. What is the benefit of using `.prop` though? I don't know myself but I like the shortness of your code.

Comment: Nice.  I never thought to do it that way.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl `prop` is the property of the DOM object vs. `attr`, which is the serialized HTML.  I'm afraid I don't know too many specifics, just that using `.attr` for disabled/checked may not work like you expect.  jQuery's API recomments using `.prop` specifically.  To quote: "The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method."

Comment: @ExplosionPills: +1 Nice one, thanks for getting back on that.

Comment: @LorenzoC your test applies the selector every time, which is wrong.  You also did not bind `.change` in the second test.  This is a better test: http://jsperf.com/11903335-11903390/2

Comment: It's very simple to write a [`toggleProp` plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/zzzzBov/pZ54Y/)

Comment: @LorenzoC, premature optimization is the root of all evil. Given that JS is an asynchronous language, most of the time is spent idling, and very little time is needed for computation. If you find that a particular bit of code is causing issues by being too slow, then you should benchmark and fix it. Otherwise, focus on writing readable code.

Comment: 1+ The update ES2015 doesn't work in (actual) Safari, that's why I like the previous one. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 8):

You can write your own plugin that does something like this.

Add this after jQuery, in a script file preferably.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.toggleDisabled = function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            this.disabled = !this.disabled;
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Then use it like this:

```
$('#my-select').toggleDisabled();
```

Courtesy: [Toggle input disabled attribute using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702000/jquery-toggle-input-disabled-attribute?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

you can check using $.is function like below

```
$("#filtri").change(function(){
    $("#menuContinenti").attr("disabled", ! $(this).is(':checked'));    
});
```