# Avoid triggering multiple click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I'm trying to make an input field disabled/enabled when I click on its sibling link.

Here is my code.

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
    var inp=$(this).siblings('input');
    inp.prop('disabled', false);
    $(this).click(function(){
        inp.prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

When I click first time it works fine, But from next time it won't work. Because the both click functions, triggers. I'm unable to overcome this issue. Please help me.

[See the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/2a2ajbnb/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [toggle disabled attribute in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903293/toggle-disabled-attribute-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just negate the `disabled` prop on every click. `elem.disabled = ! elem.disabled`.

***Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/2a2ajbnb/1/***

***Snippet:***

```js
$('a').on('click',function(){
    var $inp = $(this).siblings('input');
    $inp.prop('disabled', !$inp.prop('disabled'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="x" value="22" disabled/><a href="#">change</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
    var inp=$(this).siblings('input');
    inp.prop('disabled', !inp.prop('disabled'));

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try making it so one click function does both jobs, that's probably easier. Otherwise, just turn off the previous click function using

```
$('a').off('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('a').on('click', function() {

  if ($('#ib').attr('disabled') == 'disabled') {
    $('#ib').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('#ib').prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='ib' type="text" name="x" value="22" disabled/>
<a href="#">change</a>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/2a2ajbnb/2/)